# Faster Method of geting my mysql Data

Tags: php, mysql

On my site I experience a rather high server load time and I am thinking of ways to optimize some of my mysql queries.

What I do now:

1. First I count all the cars in the table **having certain criteria**;
2. If the **number of cars is greater then 20**, I **do that query with those criteria**;
3. If the **number is smaller**, I do a more general search just to give some results on the page.

**Is there a faster way to do this?**

It seems I am loosing performance **counting the rows with certain criteria**** and querying them once again just to get the data.

```
$car_sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$table." WHERE carid IS NOT NULL $criteria1 $criteria2 $criteria3"); 

$car_nr = mysql_result($car_sql, "0"); 

if($car_nr > 20){ 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT carid,pic0 FROM ".$table." WHERE carid IS NOT NULL $criteria1 $criteria2 $criteria3");
} else { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT carid FROM ".$table." LIMIT 20"); 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many records are in your table? Is it quite large? Usually the queries you have listed above should process pretty quickly, since it just involves one table.

Comment: we would need more information to help. what could be in criteria 1, 2 and 3? is carid your primary key? if so, why would it ever be null? if not, is carid an indexed column?

Comment: The table has about 1000 rows. The carid is primary, so you are right, I should exclude the null part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine your first and your second query as they are the basically the same:

```
$car_sql = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS carid,pic0 FROM ".$table." WHERE carid IS NOT NULL $criteria1 $criteria2 $criteria3");
```

But you would have to test if that is a lot slower than the first separate query.

It would be faster if the number of results normally is bigger than 20.

Comment: I found a performance test about this function: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: Ty, but not sure how it will help because I need the code to do something in there are more then 20 cars found and something else if the car number is less.

Comment: @webmasters What's the most common situation, more or less than 20? You could also try combining everything into one query, something like: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ((SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE $conditions) < 20) OR ($conditions)` but I doubt that that would perform better than what you have now. You could test it though.